# Sqlite query using where condition having more than one condition to satisfy

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, android-sqlite

Please find what is wrong here

here _id and chek is the column of my db  i to write a query to search those which has  id =id and check =number

```
 public Cursor query(int id){
    return myDataBase.query("question", null,"_id = "+id+ "AND " +  "chek ="+number,null, null, null, null); 


}
```

Comment: What exactly is wrong? the query isn't working, or there is an error (if that is what is wrong please also supply a logcat.)
Just based off that, I'd assume you need a space so the query is like 
                                          
myDataBase.query("question", null,"_id = "+id+ " AND " +  "chek ="+number,null, null, null, null);

Answer (score 1):

May this help you:

Replace your query with these lines..

```
public Cursor query(int id){
return myDataBase.query("question", null,"_id = "+id+ " AND " +  "chek ="+number,null, null, null, null);
```

keep space between the double quotes in And :`" And "` otherwise the string will be 
**Example:** `_id=3And check =9`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly check your sql query syntax are right or not

You can use raw query

```
 String SQL= "select * from question where _id = "+id+ " and chek ="+number+";
    Log.d("SQL::", SQL);
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(SQL, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

**try**

```
return myDataBase.query("question", null,"_id = "+id+ " AND " +  "chek ="+number,null, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your query with these lines if not yet solved..

```
public Cursor query(int id){
return myDataBase.query("question", null,"(_id = "+id+ " AND " +  "chek ="+number+")",null, null, null, null);
```